# Updating multiple spinners

Tags: android, spinner, android-adapter

I have a `listView` containing some `Spinner`s. I want to update the `Spinner`s when I select an item. For example:

- Spinner 1 : `{A, B, C}`
- Spinner 2 : `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
- Spinner 3 : `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}`

If I select A, I want to have:

- Spinner 1 : `{A, B, C}`
- Spinner 2 : `{1, 2}`
- Spinner 3 : `{d, e, f, g, h}`

And if I select 1 :

- Spinner 1 : `{A, B, C}`
- Spinner 2 : `{1, 2}`
- Spinner 3 : `{d, e, f}`

I guess I have to update the adapters, but I'm a bit confused about the `getView()` method and how to update the adapters.

I know how to have the good list, my problem is that the data don't update when I want (it's not shown).

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Critere> navDrawerItems;
    private int pos;
    public HashMap<String, String> criteres_modif;
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Spinner> spinnerList;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<Critere> navDrawerItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        criteres_modif = new HashMap<String, String>();
        spinnerList = new ArrayList<Spinner>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawerTitle);
            if (tv != null) {
                tv.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getLabel());
                spinnerList.add((Spinner) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.drawerSpinner));
                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(Catalogue.activity);
                list = db.getCritereDistinct(navDrawerItems.get(position)
                        .getTableCritere(), criteres_modif);
                dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Catalogue.activity,
                        R.layout.item_single_text, list);
                spinnerList.get(position).setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                pos = position;
                spinnerList.get(position).setOnItemSelectedListener(
                        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                if (arg2 != 0) {

                                    Log.w("Bad pos","pos : " + pos); // Always 0, it must be between 0 and 5 depending on the spinner selected
                                    if (!criteres_modif
                                            .containsKey(navDrawerItems
                                                    .get(pos).getTableCritere())) {
                                        criteres_modif.put(
                                                navDrawerItems.get(pos)
                                                        .getTableCritere(),
                                                navDrawerItems.get(pos)
                                                        .getList().get(arg2));
                                        Log.w("Key not exist", "Clé : "
                                                + navDrawerItems.get(pos)
                                                        .getTableCritere()
                                                + " Val : "
                                                + navDrawerItems.get(pos)
                                                        .getList().get(arg2));
                                    } else {
                                        criteres_modif.remove(navDrawerItems
                                                .get(pos).getTableCritere());
                                        criteres_modif.put(
                                                navDrawerItems.get(pos)
                                                        .getTableCritere(),
                                                navDrawerItems.get(pos)
                                                        .getList().get(arg2));
                                        Log.w("Key exists", "Clé : "
                                                + navDrawerItems.get(pos)
                                                        .getTableCritere()
                                                + " Val : "
                                                + navDrawerItems.get(pos)
                                                        .getList().get(arg2));
                                    }
                                    updateNavSpinners(pos);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateNavSpinners(int position) {
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(Catalogue.activity);
        for (int i = 0; i < navDrawerItems.size(); i++) {
            if (position != i) {
                navDrawerItems.get(i).setList(
                        db.getCritereDistinct(navDrawerItems.get(i)
                                .getTableCritere(), criteres_modif));
                ((BaseAdapter) spinnerList.get(i).getAdapter())
                        .notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** I updated my code. I'm getting the correct data at the beginning but when I click on an item it doesn't update the others spinners even if the data seems to be the one I need in the log. Moreover, I am getting problems to get the correct spinner selected. I have a variable called "pos" which is supposed to be the position of my spinner in my listView but its value is always 0.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to change the `getView()` logic. Just change the data associated to the adapters that must be updated, and call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on them. The view to which the adapter is bound will then update itself automatically.

Comment: I still should do it in my CustomSpinnerAdapter class, don't I? I did it in the getView() method because I thought I was supposed to fill my spinners with data for the first time here, my logic is wrong? And in my mind if I do that, then I would put my listener in it and call a method for the update in that listener

Comment: The Adapter object acts as the bridge between the Spinner view and its underlying data. The Spinner calls getView() to populate itself. Therefore, if you want to refresh, you shoud just change the data and call notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem.

An adapter keeps the reference for the list we give it, so I had to declare different lists (not just make a list in my constructor then make something like list = db.getList()).
Moreover, if we want to use notifyDataSetChanged() it works only if we use methods on the list it has in reference like add(), clear(), remove()... We can't reassign the list with something like list = db.getListUpdated().

For the problem of getting the right spinner in my list, I used the tags : I set a tag with the number of the spinner in my list on this spinner, then in my listener I use the Tag that I can find in my AdapterView to get the good spinner and all the things I need to get about it (like for example, the "type" of the spinner, "City" for a spinner containing cities).